# Why does this not save

Tags: javascript

What the code needs to do is to save the information but it does not!
Please help with this

```js
function signin() {
    var y = document.getElementById("email2");
    var x = document.getElementById("myInput");
    if (y == email2 && x == myInput) {
        window.open("account.html");
    } else {
        window.open('sign in.html');
    }
}
```

```html
<form>
   <h1>Email</h1>
   <input type="email" id="email2" required><br><br>
   <h1>Password</h1>
   <input type="password" id="myInput">
   <input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction()">Show Password<br><br>
</form>
<input type="Submit" onclick="signin()">
```

Comment: You have not defined `email2` and `MyInput`

Comment: save information where ?

Comment: And you are reading the DOM element, not the value

Comment: There is nothing in this code to "save" anything.

Comment: `if(y==email2)` doesn't mean anything. `email2` is undefined.

Comment: getElementById will return the DOM element not the input's value.

Comment: Please read the guidelines for asking questions on https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I think you actually just need to take an introductory Javascript tutorial, and read something about web development in general as well, because this is full of really basic errors - most of them mentioned in the comments above already - plus it makes no sense: 1) It doesn't "save" anything and it's unclear what you think you're saving anyway, or where to. 2) You appear to be trying to check a password in the browser... **you need to understand that this provides no security at all!**. Any user can open the developer tools and change the code, or just bypass it entirely.

Comment: ....or they could just navigate their browser directly to account.html whenever they like and ignore this page. 3) If this is a username/password form, then it's presumably already a sign-in form...so why does your (useless) security check then try to open _another_ page called "sign in" in another window whenever the test fails? Surely it would return to the existing form. Bizarre. But anyway it doesn't matter. If you want to implement a sign-in function you'll need some server-side script and a proper understanding of web security. Personally, I suggest you just use an existing package.

Answer (score 0):

I somehow don't think that this is going to save information anyway , but regardless of that :

- Your code is not correct :

  - The variable `email2` is not defined
  - The variable `MyInput` is not defined
- Also you are not storing the answer anywhere , that could be another reason why it stores nothing.

You will need to assign it somewhere to store like `localStorage` etc. define the variables `email2` and `MyInput`.

Also the variables `x` and `y` are getting the elements and not their value which I suspect you need more than the elements

or if you don't feel like reading this and doing everything just use an existing package or just navigate your browser to `account.html` directly no need of all that silly code.

Better yet do what *@ADyson* which IMO is the best idea (given in comments)

Comment: all true, but since this is basically an attempt to do client-side authentication, it's useless anyway because an attacker can just modify the JavaScript or ignore it entirely. OP needs to re-think the whole concept.

Comment: @ADyson : You don't say.

Comment: Glad you agree...but then why provide an answer which doesn't point that out? No purpose the OP spending time fixing the bugs if the code is essentially useless for its intended purpose.

Comment: @ADyson : take a look now :)